# Can I pause SlidesJS on click?

Tags: jquery

I am using [SlidesJS](http://slidesjs.com/) for a slideshow and I was wondering if there is a way to pause and play the slideshow on click of a button?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend grabbing the most current [version from github](https://github.com/nathansearles/Slides/blob/master/source/slides.js) looks like in this new version its as simple as calling `stop()` and `play()`

He has an example here showing how as well, notice the bottom left, has the option to play and stop.

http://beta.slidesjs.com/examples/standard/

Answer (score 1):

Your required functionality will work in the Slides 2 beta, but not in any version below 2
you can check out how it works here : https://github.com/nathansearles/slides/

Answer (score 0):

In your jquery.slides.js file do a search for _this.stop(true);

It shows about 3-4 times, next & previous click.. and you will also see it showing for paginationLink.click

The problem i was having was the slider was stop sliding after click either previous, next or pagination. I needed the slider to restart.. so what i did was add a setTimeout to play()

```
_this.stop(true);

setTimeout(function ()
{ _this.play(true) }, 3000);
```